# How to sort column in csv file?

Tags: python

Below is my result and I want to sort all column from left side.

```
,Xdiepos,Ydiepos,Fail Group,Instance,Bank,Fail WL,Fail BL,Fail WR,Fail bit count,Fail Type
6,27,30,BIST2,[5],Bank1,[1]_33,[1]_[26],1W0R,1,
8,27,30,BIST3,[3],,[1]_3,['[2]_[15]'],1W0R,1,
9,19,20,BIST4,[7],Bank0,[0]_0,[1]_[5],1W0R,1,
10,19,20,BIST4,[7],Bank0,[0]_0,[3]_[5],1W0R,1,
12,28,30,BIST5,[5],,[0]_36,['[0]_33'],1W0R,1,
13,34,33,BIST6,[3],,[1]_60,['[0]_39'],1W0R,1,
14,28,33,BIST7_3,[6],Bank1,[1]_26,[1]_[22],1W0R,1,
```

Below is my code and it makes error "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_value'".
How to sort this csv file??

```
type = pd.read_csv(f'address.csv')
type.sort_value(by =['Xdiepos','Ydiepos', 'Fail Group', 'Instance', 'Bank', 'Fail WL', 'Fail BL', 'Fail WR'])
type.to_csv(f'sort.csv')
```

Comment: There is a typo, the method's name is `sort_values`. Also, don't use `type` as a variable name, this is a python builtin.

Answer (score 0):

```
type.sort_values(['Xdiepos','Ydiepos', 'Fail Group', 'Instance', 'Bank', 'Fail WL', 'Fail BL', 'Fail WR'])
```

Comment: Thank you. it works. but result didn't change. I alse changed variable name 'type' . Order didn't change                                                                                                              ,Unnamed: 0,Xdiepos,Ydiepos,Fail Group,Instance,Bank,Fail WL,Fail BL,Fail WR,Fail bit count,Fail Type
0,0,27,30,BIST1_1,"[0, 1]",Bank1,[0]_0,"[0]_[[3, 7, 10], [4]], [0]_[[3, 7, 10], [4]]",1W0R,1,
1,1,27,30,BIST1_1,[1],Bank1,[1]_0,[2]_[[1]],1W0R,1,
2,2,27,30,BIST1_1,[1],Bank1,[1]_0,[2]_[[0]],1W0R,1,
3,3,27,30,BIST1_1,[0],Bank0,[0]_2,[2]_[[4]],1W0R,1,